# Can I read Hubbard and Hubbard without knowing any real analysis? I didn't read Rudin for example.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I know calculus from high school like differentiating and integrating. Will I be able to read Hubbard and Hubbard? I also want to know whether Hubbard and Hubbard has enough linear algebra for a first course in quantum mechanics based on say Griffiths.

Comment: Assuming you mean _Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms_, having some real analysis kind of helps (just a first course). I also wouldn't use it as a self-contained linear algebra text, but it can get you started. I refer you to the project paper I wrote back in 2015: https://tinyurl.com/434pkv2y

Comment: I have not done even a first course, I just know high school level of calculus, I want to know whether I can read it enough to understand my physics courses.

Comment: You may want to begin with [**Div, Grad, Curl, and All That. An Informal Text on Vector Calculus**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0393925161) by Harry M. Schey (2005, 4th edition). Also, for extremely readable introductions to some of the more basic math for quantum mechanics, you might find it useful to have [**Quantum Chemistry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321803450) by Ira N. Levine (2014, 7th edition --- most of the earlier editions would also serve this purpose). For later purposes, some of the references in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3986144/13130) might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Hubbard and Hubbard has more than enough linear algebra for a quantum mechanics course based on Griffiths, who is very good about mathematical hand-holding anyway. In the preface to Hubbard and Hubbard, the authors mention that real analysis is not a prerequisite, but they do say "[t]he book can also be used for a course in analysis, using the proofs in the Appendix." To me, that says you'll have no trouble using the book, and that if you want to understand the real analysis underlying the results in the book, the proofs are given in the appendix at an appropriate level for someone who hasn't had any exposure to real analysis.

All of that being said, if your goal is just to learn enough linear algebra for a Griffiths-level quantum mechanics course, there are other undergraduate linear algebra textbooks that are probably easier to learn from than Hubbard and Hubbard. If you plan to take a mechanics or an electricity and magnetism course, though, the vector calculus in Hubbard and Hubbard will prove extremely useful.